# Prove that $\text{Hom}(\Bbb Z/m \Bbb Z, \Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z) \cong \Bbb Z/(m, n)\Bbb Z$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> $\text{Hom}(\Bbb Z/m \Bbb Z, \Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z) \cong \Bbb Z/(m, n)\Bbb Z$

$\text{Hom}(\Bbb Z/m \Bbb Z, \Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z)$ is the group consisting of all homomorphisms from $\Bbb Z/m\Bbb Z$ to $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$. I want to show that this is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z/(m,n)\Bbb Z$, where $(m,n)$ is notation for $\gcd(m,n)$.

How should I go about constructing an isomorphism $\phi: \text{Hom}(\Bbb Z/m \Bbb Z, \Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z) \to \Bbb Z/(m, n)\Bbb Z$?

I started with thinking about the objects in $\text{Hom}(\Bbb Z/m \Bbb Z, \Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z)$. Suppose $f: \Bbb Z/m\Bbb Z \to \Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$ is a homomorphism. It is completely determined by $f(1)$ alone, which has $n$ options for itself in $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$. This is because: if $f(1) = a \in \Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$, we have $f(x) = f(1) + f(1) + ... + f(1)$ ($x$ times) $= ax$.

What do I do next? Perhaps I am overcounting in some sense, or maybe some of these choices of $f(1)$ do not result in homomorphisms, because $\Bbb Z/(m,n)\Bbb Z$ has only $(m,n)$ elements, which in general is less than $n$. What am I missing? How do I work through this problem?

Thanks a lot for your help!

P.S. I'm familiar with elementary group theory, i.e. topics including group actions, Cauchy and Sylow's theorems, etc. - nothing too fancy - so simpler answers would be nicer!

Comment: I think that $f([1]_m)$ cannot be *any* of the $n$ elements in $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$, since $[0]_n = f([0]_m) = f([m]_m) = f(m[1]_m) = mf([1]_m)$, and then the order of $f([1]_m)$ divides $m$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track, but when you try to define $ f: \mathbb{Z} / m\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z} / n\mathbb{Z} $ by $ f(1) = a $, then you need to check that this is well-defined. For this, you need $ f(m) = ma $ to be equal to $0 \in \mathbb{Z} / n\mathbb{Z}$. (Convince yourself why this is necessary and also why this is sufficient for $f$ to be well-defined.) This will constrain what values of $a$ actually produce a well-defined $f$.

Comment: How do I check that $f$ is *well-defined*? Does well-defined mean that for every $x$, $f(x)$ is a unique value?

Comment: Yes, and since $m = 0$ in $\mathbb{Z} / m\mathbb{Z}$, then you better have $f(m) = f(0)$ in $\mathbb{Z} / n\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Great, so we must pick $a \in \{0,1,\ldots,n-1\}$ such that $ma = 0 \in \Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$. In other words, $ma$ should be a multiple of $n$, i.e. $n|ma$. I'm still struggling with showing that we have only $(m,n)$ possibilities now.

Comment: Good progress. Letting $d = \gcd(m,n)$, try writing $m = m' d$ and $n = n' d$, where $\gcd(m', n') = 1$.

Comment: Thanks, Michael. I am able to see that $n|ma \implies n'|m'a$ which means $n'|a$. Here, $n' = n/d$ as you have defined. Must I now argue that $n'$ divides only $d$ numbers in $\{0,1,2,\ldots,n-1\}$? If yes, how?

Comment: Try some examples with different values of $m$ and $n$ and I'm confident you'll see the pattern.